# Issue with FirebaseRecyclerAdapter. Firebase UI 1.2.0 compared to 4.3.1

Tags: java, android

I am currently following a tutorial to add real-time location tracking to my application. I have run into some issues since the creator of the tutorial is using firebase-ui-auth:1.2.0 compared to the latest release firebase-ui-auth:4.3.1.

the link to the tutorial is below:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=17HqLBkuX-E <-- I am currently stuck at 27:30

I am aware that FirebaseRecyclerAdapter has received some changes, changing populateViewHolder to onBindViewHolder & onCreateViewHolder.

The issue I am having while following this tutorial is, the original code is written as the following:

```
 private void updateList() {
        adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<UserRace, OnlineListViewHolder>(
                UserRace.class,
                R.layout.user_layout,
                OnlineListViewHolder.class,
                counterRef
        ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(OnlineListViewHolder viewHolder, UserRace model, int position) {
                viewHolder.txtEmail.setText(model.getEmail());

            }
        };
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        onlineList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

while version 4.3.1 is written as:

```
private void updateList() {
        adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<UserRace, OnlineListViewHolder>(
                UserRace.class,
                R.layout.user_layout,
                OnlineListViewHolder.class,
                counterRef
        ) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull OnlineListViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull UserRace model) {

                holder.txtEmail.setText(model.getEmail());
            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public OnlineListViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
                return null;
            }
        };
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        onlineList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

I receive an error in this version of the code on the following lines:

```
                UserRace.class,
                R.layout.user_layout,
                OnlineListViewHolder.class,
                counterRef
        ) {
```

Red lines will appear under the values within the brackets with it being stated that: FirebaseRecyclerAdapter() in FirebaseRecyclerAdapter cannot be applied to:
Expected Parameters:
Actual Arguments:

Using version 1.2.0 to avoid this error allows this area of the code to function but messes with other areas of my application.

Is there any way for me to contain the required data within the brackets without receiving an error? I have tried to research this issue but I am not proficient in java so I have not been able to find a solution to this.

If anything is unclear with what I have stated, please let me know.

All help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code was deprecated and now you need to use `FirebaseRecyclerOptions` to setup your RecyclerView Adapter, please read the documentation here

https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md

Now, instead of doing this

```
  adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<UserRace, OnlineListViewHolder>(
                UserRace.class,
                R.layout.user_layout,
                OnlineListViewHolder.class,
                counterRef
        )
```

you will need to it like this

First, configure the adapter by building FirebaseRecyclerOptions

```
FirebaseRecyclerOptions<UserRace> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<UserRace>()
                        .setQuery(query, UserRace.class)
                        .build();
```

Next create the FirebaseRecyclerAdapter object. You should already have a ViewHolder subclass for displaying each item.

```
adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<UserRace, OnlineListViewHolder>(options) {
    @Override
    public OnlineListViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        // Create a new instance of the ViewHolder, in this case we are using a custom
          View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.yourCustomLayout, parent, false);

          return new OnlineListViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(OnlineListViewHolder holder, int position, UserRace model) {
        // Bind the views
        // ...
    }
};
```

And last but not least, this is a very important part, do this at your `onStart()` and `onStop()` methods

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    adapter.startListening();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    adapter.stopListening();
}
```

This is an example, you must adapt it for your use case